# Getting 'Path not found' when using CreateTextFile

Tags: javascript, syntax, internet-explorer-8, text-files

I am trying to create a textfile but I get a `Path not found` error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fo = fso.GetFolder("\\logs")
    var a = fo.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", true);
    a.WriteLine("This is a test.");
    a.Close();
```

I am using javascript in IE8. Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is in Windows Scripting Host or similar?

Comment: Try saving a file from notepad to C:\logs\testfile.txt. What does this tell you?

Comment: It sounds like there's no `logs` directory at the root of whatever drive is the current drive when you run this script.

Comment: @SecurityMatt: You mean `\logs\testfile.txt` (the first backslash in the string in `GetFolder` is just to escape the second one in the string literal, the path only starts with one).

Comment: @SecurityMatt I created a file in the directory too to see if that would do something and I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first making sure that the logs directory exists. Next, try including the entire path of the logs directory within the source. This is since the default path of FileSystemObject is the current working directory.

For example, if logs is under C:\logs\

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fo = fso.GetFolder("C:\\logs")
    var a = fo.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", true);
    a.WriteLine("This is a test.");
    a.Close();
```